# MongoDB array duplicates

Tags: arrays, mongodb, count, duplicates

I have the following query, this makes a new array using lookup, in order to "join" two collections, once merged the data, y grouped by "group" the data and show the events field, as you can see it have duplicates, like "times this issue happened" that is what it means. I want to show something like:

```
Group1
{
Event 1 : 120 Times
Event 2 : 2478 Times
Event 3 : 120 Times
}

Group2
{
Event 1 : 455 Times
Event 2 : 24  Times
Event 3 : 146 Times
}
```

My code

```
 db.events.aggregate([

   { $match : { netcode : "N000362" } },

    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "nodes",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "name",
          as: "event_joined"


        }

   },


  { $unwind:  {path: "$event_joined"}},


  { $project : { name : 1, event : 1, "event_joined.group": 1 ,_id:0} },

  { $unwind:  {path: "$event_joined"}},

  { $group : { _id : "$event_joined.group", eventos: { $push: "$event"} } },


])
```

The output:[image: From Robo Mongo]

```
{
"_id" : "GFS-CALL-CENTER-EXTENDIDO",
"eventos" : [ 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "SNMP DOWN", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Reachability", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive CPU", 
    "Proactive Response Time", 
    "Proactive Memory Free", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Availability", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "BGP Peer Down", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
    "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "BGP Peer Down", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Reachability", 
        "Proactive CPU", 
        "Proactive Response Time", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Memory Free", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "BGP Peer Down", 
        "Proactive Interface Availability", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "BGP Peer Down", 
        "Proactive Reachability", 
        "Proactive CPU", 
        "Proactive Response Time", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Memory Free", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "BGP Peer Down", 
        "Proactive Interface Availability", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Reachability", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "BGP Peer Down", 
        "Proactive Response Time", 
        "Proactive CPU", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Memory Free", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 

    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "GFS-INTERNET",
    "eventos" : [ 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Reachability", 
        "Proactive Response Time", 
        "Proactive CPU", 
        "Proactive Memory Free", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Availability", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Reachability", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Response Time", 
        "Proactive CPU", 
        "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Memory Free", 
        "Proactive Interface Input Utilisation", 
        "Proactive Interface Availability"
    ]
}
```

And it goes and goes, well hope you can help me, i searched and tried in MongoDB documentation, but in my opinion it lacks very much of examples and syntax

Comment: Use `{ $addToSet: "$event"}` instead of `{ $push: "$event"}` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/.  Also looks like your `$project +  $unwind` stage is redundant.

Comment: You Again, Thank you, I'll try it quickly, dont leave please :D

Comment: Indeed it's redundant, i was just testing, is there a way to see how much of each one i have?

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicates tho, i want to see how much of each one i have

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your post. Try `{ $group : { _id : {group:"$event_joined.group", event:"$event"}, count: { $sum: 1} } }`

Comment: The query is good, buut, it ummm, ungroup the query i think...

this is the poutput


https://pastebin.com/7ABuE130

Comment: Okay add second group `{ $group : { _id : "$_id.group",  "eventandcount": {$push:{event:"$_id.event", count:{$sum: "$count"} } } } }`. This will $group by `group` and output `events` with `count`.